# Windows Boot Manager interfering with Kubuntu 18.04.1 installation on old netbook

Tags: boot, kubuntu, bios

I am completely new to Linux. Now I want to install Kubuntu on my old Acer Aspire-Netbook to practice a little bit for my internship.

I created a bootable USB-Memory-Stick, changed its priority to the highest in the boot-section of the bios (no uefi - old blue white interface).

Windows 7 Starter is installed on that netbook, when I try to boot from USB Windows Boot Manager jumps in and says: Windows failed to start.

I read about a secure boot but I do not have this option in BIOS (its only available on uefi-bios?)

Is there a way for me to install Kubuntu anyways on this netbook?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: The  "Linux Live USB Creator" was not copying all needed Files to the USB-stick, so I created a new bootable device with "Rufus" and now the installation is nearly complete.